# How to use VisualStateManager to set an Element inside a ListViewItem visible when the ListViewItem gains focus

Tags: xaml, visualstatemanager, uwp

In my UWP, I am trying to create a ListView that its DataTemplate will contain a TextBox and an invisible AppBarButton. What I want to do, is when the TextBox gains focus or the item is clicked, the AppBarButton to be set to Visible. So I created a ControlTemplate which contains a VisualStateManager and the AppBarButton and set it to the DataTemplate of my ListView.

**The ControlTemplate:**

```
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="TelephoneTemplate" TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
                    <AppBarButton x:Name="DeleteIcon"  Icon="Cancel" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Foreground="{StaticResource TextGreyBrush}" Height="40" Width="40" Margin="0 0 -12  0"  Command="{Binding ElementName=ClientOverviewView, Path=DataContext.ClientDetailsViewModel.RemoveTelephoneCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                        <AppBarButton.RenderTransform>
                            <CompositeTransform ScaleX="0.8" ScaleY="0.8"/>
                        </AppBarButton.RenderTransform>
                    </AppBarButton>
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DeleteIcon" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DeleteIcon" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DeleteIcon" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>

                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DeleteIcon" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>

                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
```

**The ListView:**

```
<ListView Grid.Row="2"   ItemsSource="{Binding ClientDetailsViewModel.ClientDetailsModel.Telephones}"  SelectionMode="None"  Margin="-10 4 -10 0" IsItemClickEnabled="True" >
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ListViewItem Template="{StaticResource TelephoneTemplate}">
                                <ListViewItem.Content>
                                    <TextBox
                                            PlaceholderText="Telefon (erforderlich)"
                                            InputScope="TelephoneNumber"
                                            BorderThickness="1"
                                            BorderBrush="{StaticResource TextGreyBrush}"
                                            Foreground="{StaticResource TextGreyBrush}"
                                            Text="{Binding ContactText, Mode=TwoWay}" >

                                    </TextBox>
                                </ListViewItem.Content>
                            </ListViewItem>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

The VisualState "Normal" seems to work because when I set its value to "Collapsed" the  AppBarButton is invisible. But when I click to a ListViewItem the visibility of the AppBarButton remains invisible. I tried with many visible states but it doesn't work.

Comment: You are doing it very wrong. The `ListViewItem` shouldn't be wrapped within the `DataTemplate`. You might want to find out the relationship between them first. I'd put the delete button and all the visual states inside the `DataTemplate` and have the `ListViewItem` untouched.

Comment: @JustinXL  the problem is that if I put the VisualStateManger inside the DataTemplate, it doesn't work at all.

Comment: Try `GoToStateAction`.